# Spread operator to assign API response to interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Code example for this question here: [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwBEUqDLwDcAKFGhIsDsAEAjFMQ5ceverKQLiAehRgwIieGjw1GrUm3qBhGNCSHRaCADtbM+YqQBhV+oDmcAC8uKxi1ppeAHTALsAwwCgANsAAXkgAgvoAFBEWvi4BAJRizm7wACZywR6RxFERtvbZJeJIAB5SlUj0KPhJlXJiEi6UUL1oSHAZ+HYgFMCuuKJwcMAVAFxwtlCx-mKrLiggSFs7ewdwMACeYKfbMLsu+ytw6AkAbvdyEBBJqC5Lo9gP5-EgoFscK9VuszsDnpdVu9gF8tj8-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-hHHI-zsWAKAsScYxqRpdxwERJBIDApaUBkGD4hWsx-viCZEVE8mrAAKppbk6ZsekIgZRlwCAi42s8VzYRwfxJBA0YUXRTHggkl7CaR0VEZWBZEXyxy4TcdzYMiXzYMCoLgo1LgMQATMl9hhUhsE5pVX54FEY2ScBI4tNgukTesbCtGqrLEr2A7DuQMGrKw2BUotxICDA+BQIR2REmWCZndoF2rK0rBAA)

I have interface for object with a lot of properties:

```js
interface Automation {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  active: boolean;
  trigger: {
    id: string;
    active: boolean;
    conditions: {
      all: [];
      any: [];
    };
  };
  createdAt: number;
  updatedAt: number;
  agent?: {
    language: string;
    model: string;
    version: number;
    trainedAt: number;
  };
...
...
...
  ];
```

State hook for this object:

```js
const [automation, setAutomation] = useState<Automation>({});
```

And getting document with the same data from Firestore:

```js
const doc = await db.collection(someCollection).doc(someId).get();
```

And I would like to assign this firestore document to state using setAutomation:

```js
setAutomation({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
```

And I'm getting error:

```js
Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Automation>'.
  Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Automation': name, type, active, trigger, and 2 more.
```

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to use spread operator with doc.data() method and make TypeScript don't worry about the data types?

Comment: Maybe, but without a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) I'm not sure.  The easier you make it for others to demonstrate the issue for themselves, the more likely it is you'll get a useful answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Typescript does infer spread types, so you don't have to do anything for that. The issue may be that `doc.data()` returns `object`, and typescript doesn't know that this `object` is supposed to be `Automation`. So you'll probably have to cast it `...(doc.data() as Automation)`. Actually I can't be sure about that, because I don't know firebase typings, but this is the most likely reason

Comment: @AlexChashin "...(doc.data() as Automation)" this actually solves my problem. Thank's a lot!